# Consolidate DB values to nearest whole value

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Apologies for vagueness of this question and the lack of code but I've been trying to solve it all day and am nowhere close to even a starting point...

I have an Access DB full of values like this:

```
Distance | Spend
-------------------------
78       | 203
26       | 48
124      | 145
45       | 50
```

I would like to create a new table from this with the distances rounded to multiples of 50 and the spend averaged, so in this example it would look like this:

```
Distance | Spend
-------------------------
50       | 49
100      | 174
```

I'm using VB.NET
My only idea was to cycle though the records and add them to KeyValue pairs like this, but I would end up with over 100 of these so not really workable.

```
 Dim list50 As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer))
 Dim list100 As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer))
```

Comment: Why do you show 2 records in the example output? Why not 4 or 1?

Comment: I'm showing that the Distance records of 26 and 45 have been consolidated to the nearest 50, 50 in this case and 78 and 134 have been consolidated to 100, with the spend values averaged.

Comment: Sorry, my question was wrong, I've changed the 134 to 124 so it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following SQL should yield the desired result:

```sql
select 50*(fix(t.distance/50+0.5)) as distance, avg(t.spend) as spend
from table1 t
group by 50*(fix(t.distance/50+0.5))
```

Alternatively, using the `round` function:

```sql
select 50*(round(t.distance/50,0)) as distance, avg(t.spend) as spend
from table1 t
group by 50*(round(t.distance/50,0))
```

Change `table1` to the name of your table.

Comment: Be aware that in Access, Round function uses banker's (even/odd) rounding rule but Format does not. This is why I use a custom function for rounding.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick, the bankers rounding rule doesn't have a negative impact in this case anyway.

Comment: @June7 Many thanks - I wasn't aware of that subtlety.